# Error when trying to use Semantic components

Tags: javascript, typescript, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to use a Semantic UI React Transition component.  I have Semantic installed and importing it:

```
import { 
  Transition,
 } from "semantic-ui-react";

import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

When I try to use it:

```
return (
  <div> 
    {
      <div>
      <Transition
        visible={this.state.shouldShowMessageBar}
        animation="scale"
        duration={500}>
          <MessageBar
            messageBarType={ this.state.messageBarStatus.type }
            onDismiss={ () => this.setState({ shouldShowMessageBar: false }) }
          >
            { this.state.messageBarStatus.description }
          </MessageBar>
       </Transition>

      .../

      </div>
    }
  </div>
);
```

It gives a warning:

```
Warning - [webpack] 'dist':
./node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/es/lib/shallowEqual.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\...\Dev\truckDeliverySchedule\node_modules\source-map-loader\index.js!C:\...\Dev\truckDeliverySchedule\node_modules\semantic-ui-react\dist\es\lib\shallowEqual.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\...\Dev\truckDeliverySchedule\node_modules\source-map-loader\index.js!C:\...\Dev\truckDeliverySchedule\node_modules\semantic-ui-react\dist\es\lib\index.js
* C:\...\Dev\truckDeliverySchedule\node_modules\source-map-loader\index.js!C:\...\Dev\truckDeliverySchedule\node_modules\semantic-ui-react\dist\es\lib\shallowequal.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\...\Dev\truckDeliverySchedule\node_modules\source-map-loader\index.js!C:\...\Dev\truckDeliverySchedule\node_modules\semantic-ui-react\dist\es\lib\shallowEqual.js
```

I import about a dozen Office UI Fabric React components also:

```
../
import { 
  Dialog,
  DialogType,
  DialogFooter,
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/dialog';
import { 
  MessageBar,
  MessageBarType,
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/messageBar';
../
```

I'm not sure what the error is trying to say or how to fix it.

EDIT:

```
├─ webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2
├─ webpack-sources@1.1.0
├─ webpack-stream@4.0.3
├─ webpack@3.11.0
```

...

```
├─ semantic-ui-css@2.3.3
├─ semantic-ui-react@0.82.3
```

...

```
├─ react-dom@15.6.2
├─ react@15.6.2
```

Comment: I think this issue may have been previously fixed in SUIR. What version are you running? Also, what version of Webpack are you using?

Comment: @brianespinosa, I updated the question with my versions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an older version of React. [SUIR had a breaking change at 0.82.0 updating to React 16+](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0820-2018-07-06). You either need to use SUIR 0.81.0 or update your React version to 16+.